# How can i create a array with double GET variables

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, get

i have a form with some checkboxes. if i activate a ceckbox, jquery is sending the data with the .serialize() function to a php file via ajax. The problem is, that jquery send some double parameters. Here is the Query:

`area=26-50&area=51-75&area=76-100&area=100&std=1&std=3`

How can i create a array like this:

`array(
 'area' => array(0 => '26-50',1 => '51-75',2 => '76-100'), std => array(0 => 1,1 => 3)
)`

PHP overwrites the last variable with a new one...

Thanks for the help!

greetings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[]` notation will make it possible to transmit array data in a form.

Name the checkboxes in the form like this:

```
<input name="area[]" type="checkbox" value="51-75">
```

this should build an array of all selected check boxes.

Answer (score 2):

PHP can support this if the key name is appended with `[]`:

```
area[]=26-50&area[]=51-75&area[]=76-100&area[]=100&std[]=1&std[]=3
/*
Array
(
    [area] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26-50
            [1] => 51-75
            [2] => 76-100
            [3] => 100
        )

    [std] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

)
*/
```